# Post a simple react form - node, axios, nodemailer, backend, postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, axios, nodemailer

I've set up a react form running on http://localhost:3000/about and I've the backend running on port 5000 (localhost:5000). On react's package.json I set up "proxy":"localhost:5000:.

When I use postman and I send the post to localhost:5000/api/contact, the email is sent correctly (I send the data as JSON - name, email and message). Status 200

When I use the react form, the data is well prepared as json but I can't figure out the baseURL to send correctly the method post. status 404. I tried:
localhost:3000/about/api/contact;
localhost:3000/api/contact;
localhost:3000/api.... None works...

FYI
the server is set up with the following middleware and is working ok:

```
app.use('/api',contactRoute)

the controller is imported and coded as following:

router.post('/contact', (req, res)=>{
    const data = req.body;
```

The React part is not posting correctly with axios and is coded as following:

```
onSubmit: async (values) => {
        //values.preventDefault();

        try {

            const data = (JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
            setLoader(true);
            console.log(data)
            await axios.post('/contact', data);
```

The method post in react is never completed, when I check the console.log of data, is correctly structured as JSON...[status 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDrtj.png)

Answer (score 0):

use the post parameter in your axois request  {port: 5000} then It will use your actual backend port.

Comment: thanks for your reply. A last thing if you could help. I set a webpage that has is structured as follow: www.localhost:3000.com, then www.localhost:3000.com/services, www.localhost:3000.com/about, www.localhost:3000.com/contactMe. As I'm using axios from www.localhost:3000.com/contactMe, when I do the post of the form, I'm getting an error because is missing the parameter "contactMe" on my post request. Thru postman I can see that the post method works correctly for localhost:3000/api/contact and localhost:5000/api/contact and is not working for localhost:3000/contactMe/api/contact

Answer (score 0):

By default, axios uses the base path from the URL. So, here when an API request is made.

```
await axios.post('/contact', data);
```

It is actually making the post request on localhost:3000 rather than your backend server at localhost:5000. Also, "api" should also be prepended.

One simple way is to use absolute URL which should work.

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/contact', data);
```